# How to set headers in $http.get method in angular2

Tags: angular2-services

```
let headers1 = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        headers1.append('X-Authorization','some code');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers1,body: {} });
      this.http.get('http://locahost:8080/dmat/logmgr/v1/reports/all?calFilterType=Day&date=2017-05-05'+paramerter,  options ).subscribe(
        (data => {
          if(data.json().status === '200'){
                console.log('data',data);
          }else {

          };
        })
      );
```

No error in Console. but i am not able to see my header in Requested Headers tab under network tab in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
headers = new Headers();


getData() {
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.get('URL',{headers: this.headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: this is my service file                                                                         
 private headers : any;
 constructor (private http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
    }
 private getReports = 'reports/all?calFilterType=Day&date=2017-05-05';
getLogData(parameter : any) {
         //this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         this.headers.append('X-Authorization','SOME TOKEN');
  return this.http.get(this.Url+this.getReports+parameter,{headers: this.headers}) .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

Comment: THIS IS MY COMPONET FILE FROM WHERE I AM CALLING THIS SERVICE                                                                                     
    public getLogData(value : any){
        this.logManagerService.getLogData(value).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.testResponse = data;
          console.log("I CANT SEE DATA HERE: ", this.testResponse);
        }
    );